# Programatically import ICS files to iCalendar

Tags: python, icalendar

I've written an ICS file using the iCalendar module and python.

My trouble is, how can I tell iCalendar to read the ICS file? I thought I could put it in ~/Library/iCalendar/<--->/Events but it seems that just stores the ICS files once they've been imported.

Does anyone know a way I could do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You would use Applescript or Python [scripting bridge framework](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/scriptingbridge.html). In either case, tell iCal to add the events.

An example (in Applescript):

```
tell application "iCal"
   tell calendar "Work"
      set theDate to current date
      make new event at end with properties {description:"The Event Description", 
         summary:"Event Name", location:"Main Street", start date:theDate, 
         allday event:true}
   end tell
end tell
```

Or use the same method to just tell iCal to open and import that file.

Comment: both you and LaC make the same point, telling iCal to open and import the file. That's what I need to do. But I don't know how. Where can I find out the sytnax or function calls to do that? I guess AppleScript would be easier.

Comment: google is your friend. try the terms `ical applescript open ics`. I saw several solutions doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You could tell iCal to open the ics file.